# Python speech recognition is not working in window-based GUI application (It's an .exe application with hidden console)

Tags: python, pyqt5, speech-recognition

I've created a desktop application using pyqt5 python. It can generate text from audio files. (for that I'm using python speech recognition) It works totally fine if I run the script using vs code, pycharm, and terminal. But when I convert it into a .exe file and try to run it; I can run the application (GUI), but speech recognition does not work. However, I have also noticed that If I convert the .py file into a console-based .exe, it also works perfectly. That means the speech recognition function works in a console-based window, not in just a window-based application. But my goal is to create a window-based application, not a console-based one. I assume the problem is in the speech recognition function.

I used this command to create a windowed exe: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --windowed "Python_file.py"

and my speech recognition function

```
import speech_recognition as sr
class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):  
    any_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.is_running = True
    def run():
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        try:
            audio = 'path/audio.wav'
            text = r.recognize_google(audio, language= 'en-us')
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return e
        self.any_signal.emit(text) 
    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False
        self.terminate()
class Ui_Text_genarator(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Text_genarator, self).__init__() 
        uic.loadUi('A_to_T.ui', self)
        self.Generate_pushButton.clicked.connect(self.generate)
    def generate(self):
        self.thread = ThreadClass(lang, path, parent=None)
        self.thread.start()
        self.thread.any_signal.connect(self.my_function)
    def my_function(self, text):
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_Text_genarator() 
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please don't post a new question after deleting a previous one that is absolutely identical. If you edit a post and add information, please notify us by using comments so that we can review the changes and better understand the question: we cannot monitor all posts, if we ask questions and you answer by editing, we might not know it. That said, you say that the UI works and the recognition does not: did you try to run it in a command prompt and see if any output is printed by the speech recognition module and functions? Have you tried to add some debugging messages in the thread that runs it?

Comment: Also, is the UI still responding even after trying to start the recognition multiple times?